# Django-rest-framework + React-Admin : URL Backslash issue

Tags: django-rest-framework, react-admin

I have a django rest api that implements viewsets as highlighted below.

```
class SubjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = ContentRangeHeaderPagination
    queryset = Subject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubjectSerializer
```

Similarly, my frontend is based on react-admin [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import { NonIndividualList, NonIndividualCreate, NonIndividualEdit} from './subjects';

const App = () => (<Admin dataProvider=simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp')}>

<Resource name="subject" title="Non-Individuals" list={NonIndividualList} 
create={NonIndividualCreate} edit={NonIndividualEdit}/>
</Admin>);
export default App;
```

In my rest server, under settings.py I have the following settings

> APPEND_SLASH = False

Finally, my app/urls.py looks like this

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/v1/coreapp/subject', views.SubjectViewSet)

urlpatterns = [(r'^', include(router.urls)),]
```

Question:

From postman, I can comfortably crud the endpoint

- GET: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject/,
- POST:http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject/,
- Put: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject/2/,
- Delete: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject/1/,

However, my react-admin client doesnot append a trailing slash

Instead, Http-actions Create/Put send the requests to url. 
Notice the missing trailing backslash?

> http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject

I have tried to,

1- Set the Append_Slash = True
2- Added a / to the resource name, which simply appends two backslash

```
<Resource name="subject/"/>
```

> http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp/subject//2

for PUT, notice the additional backslash.

Bottom line is, my server accepts requests whenever they have a trailing backslash.

My react-admin app doesnot append the backslash on requests. 
Please SO, advise a brother :-)

Comment: Please do include your react-admin code also

Comment: How would you resolve the issue ? By handling URL without trailing slashes with DRF or adding trailing slashes thanks to React Admin ?

Comment: @Harikrishnan

I've added the code. 
Please feel free to request any additional info that will help you assist me.

Answer (score 2):

@gildas-garcia

I followed your answer and as much as it made sense, the issue arose once again. 
When a request is sent the / is added at the end of the URL var after the query parameters have been appended

> Desired URL (add a backslash before the ?)

http://localhost:8000/api/ps/nonindividual/?filter=%7B%7D&range=%5B0%2C9%5D&sort=%5B%22id%22%2C%22DESC%22%5D

> When i follow your answer i get(backslash added at the end of the complete URL)

http://localhost:8000/api/ps/nonindividual?filter=%7B%7D&range=%5B0%2C9%5D&sort=%5B%22id%22%2C%22DESC%22%5D/

Moving forward, I opted to find the indexOf the ? in the URL and added the backslash at that index

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {

    var pos = url.indexOf('?');
    var b = "/";
    var _url = [url.slice(0, pos), b, url.slice(pos)].join('');

    //url = url + '/';
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(_url, options);
}

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/coreapp', httpClient)


const App = () => (    
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}
    <Resource name="subject" list={SubjectList} create={SubjectCreate} edit={SubjectEdit}/>
    </Admin>);

    export default App;
```

> 

Comment: You're mutating the url which is always a bad idea. You should declare a new variable instead and pass it to the `fetchJson` function

Comment: However, I don't get what issue you have now. Can you provide more details ?

Comment: @GildasGarcia

No issues, I was able to resolve my error. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

By default the URLs created by `DefaultRouter` are appended with a trailing slash. This behavior can be modified by setting the trailing_slash argument to False when instantiating the router. For example:

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

Comment: I have been looking for this solution. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's the job of your `dataProvider` to transform the request in the shape expected by your backend and to use the correct url.

In your case, you'll have to customize the httpClient as explained in the dataProvider [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-simple-rest#adding-custom-headers):

```
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    let finalUrl = `${url}/`;
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(finalUrl, options);
}
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

- One solution may be using special dataProvider which is written for DRF.  [Here you can find it](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html)
- Also, you when you are specifying URL route append slash at the end:

  `urlpatterns = [
      path('rolls/', SomeListView.as_view()),]`